# jquery parent-selector combine with contains-selector

Tags: jquery, css, contains

I want to hide a text that contains the word "translation" and also hide the parent class.

I use

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("h4:contains(translation)").css("display", "none");
    });
</script>
```

This works fine and hides a text containing the word "translation"

How may I extend this hide up to the parent class which I call "class="article-list-item"?

I tried

$("article-list-item > contains(translation)").css("display", "none");

But it does not hide everything up to the sample class class="article-list-item" .. any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [:has()](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) jQuery selector:

```
$(".article-list-item:has(h4:contains(translation))").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: you have any tip, what is the difference between ":has" and ":contains"?

Comment: These are different selectors with different purpose, check the DOC. `:has()` let you select a container by filtering its content